# Expected dense_3_input to have shape (None, 40) but got array with shape (40, 1)

Tags: python, audio, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am a beginner at Deep Learning and am attempting to practice the implementation of Neural Networks in Python by performing audio analysis on a dataset. I have been following the [Urban Sound Challenge](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/08/audio-voice-processing-deep-learning/) tutorial and have completed the code for training the model, but I keep running into errors when trying to run the model on the test set.

Here is my code for creation of the model and training:

```python
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten

num_labels = y.shape[1]
filter_size = 2

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(256, input_shape = (40,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_labels))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, y, batch_size=32, epochs=40, validation_data=(val_X, val_Y))
```

Running model.summary() before fitting the model gives me:

```python
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 256)               10496     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_3 (Activation)    (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 10)                2570      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_4 (Activation)    (None, 10)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 13,066
Trainable params: 13,066
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

After fitting the model, I attempt to run it on one file so that it can classify the sound.

```python
file_name = ".../UrbanSoundClassifier/test/Test/5.wav"
test_X, sample_rate = librosa.load(file_name,res_type='kaiser_fast')
mfccs = np.mean(librosa.feature.mfcc(y=test_X, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40).T,axis=0)
test_X = np.array(mfccs)
print(model.predict(test_X))
```

However, I get

```python
ValueError: Error when checking : expected dense_3_input to have shape
```

(None, 40) but got array with shape (40, 1)

Would someone kindly like to point me in the right direction as to how I should be testing the model? I do not know what the input for `model.predict()` should be.

Full code can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/ssapcsea/6db4a9ebfab93c017de3bba9ec517bae).

Comment: Have you checked shape for both train and test audio files?, including `sample_rate`. They need to be same , else you will need to convert test to be same as train.

Comment: Your `test_X` needs to be of the exact same type (including shape) with your `X` used for training

Comment: In your X and val_X you have an additional "batch_size" column, which is missing in your test_X. Use the solution of Marcin https://stackoverflow.com/a/48239160/4132383 or np.expand_dims(test_X, axis=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So:

1. The easiest fix to that is simply reshaping `test_x`:

   ```
   test_x = test_x.reshape((1, 40))
   ```
2. More sophisticated is to reuse the pipeline you have for the creation of `train` and `valid` set also for a test set. Please, notice that the process you applied to data files is totally different in case of `test`. I'd create a test dataframe:

   ```
   test_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'filename': ["here path to test file"]}
   ```

   and then reused existing pipeline for creation of validation set.

Comment: Even when I put test_x = text_x.reshape((1,40)), I still get an error. The error is ('Error when checking : expected dense_3_input to have shape (None, 40) but got array with shape (40, 1)', 'occurred at index 0')

Comment: Are you sure you are feeding the right matrix? Can you share the code snippet?

Comment: Seemingly I had made a mistake earlier and the, `test_X = test_X.reshape((1,40))` did the trick! Thank you for the help! I was wondering if you could help me interpret the output, however? From `print(model.predict(test_X))` I got:

`[[  2.88744161e-16   2.31273791e-08   1.15574961e-14   9.50696986e-12
    9.92713869e-01   5.40378940e-13   3.16615818e-08   7.28613138e-03
    2.81731734e-16   1.57086722e-11]]`

I do not understand what these numbers mean as this is supposed to be a classification problem. How am I supposed to interpret these? @MarcinMożejko

Comment: As one may easily check - these numbers are positive numbers that sum up to `1`. This might be interpreted as a probability that a given example belongs to the class `i`. Another thing - I'd mind an upvote - I dream about gold badge from `keras` ;)